# <BPEL fault>Conflicting receive. A similar receive activity is being declared in the same process. oracle BPM faults

Tags: oracle, soa, business-process-management

Non Recoverable System Fault :
0Conflicting receive. A similar receive activity is being declared in the same process. Another receive activity or equivalent (currently, onMessage branch in a pick activity) has already been enabled with the partnerLink

Comment: The reason for the error is because a signal event expects the correlation to be established within the input arguments of the start activity. If it is not, then it gets established with a default value and so the second instance that is created will fail since two instances cannot have the same correlation value.  Additionally, if you try to notify via the signal activity, using the correlation that you expected, it won't work because the signal event was established with a default value.

Comment: Solution Establish the correlation within the start arguments or consider using another design..